Solve and understand a NDSolve error: Step Size effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected
I am trying to solve the non-linear differential equation:
$$ \ddot{x}(t) =\frac{3kx(t)}{\gamma^2}\left[kx^4(t)-2 \right] $$
numerically on Mathematica, but I can not find a solution.
My code is:
k = 1;
\[Gamma] = 1;
NDSolve[{-6k x[t] + 3k^2 x[t]^5 - \[Gamma]^2 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 5}] 

and running it, I receive the following error:
NDSolve::ndsz:  At  t  ==  0.853147811022917', step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

The equation goes to zero for $x(t) =0 $ and $x(t)= (2/k)^{1/4}$, so I suppose the error may be due to that.
I tried the methods "ExplicitRungeKutta" and "StiffnessSwitching" but they did not help. Moreover, a change in the boundary conditions gave a scalar solution, which is not desired.
Can anyone help me to solve this? I also want to understand why the problem occurs at $t= 0.853147811022917$.

Solutions to this ODE are hyperelliptic functions. The issue comes from  singularities of solutions which are determined form initial (boundary) conditions and values of constants $k$ and $\gamma$ .  You can compare the problem at hand with those which have solutions in terms of elliptic functions e.g. 1, 2

Perhaps certain solutions are free of singularities (globally regular), otherwise you cannot get rid of singularities and then you can try to understand why they appear,  what are conditions for regular or singular solutions.

If you plot x[t] as far as you can, you will see it blows up there.

Numerically, we can Look at the vector field with Manipulate:
With[{vf = 
   Prepend[SolveValues[{-6 k x[t] + 
         3 k^2 x[t]^5 - \[Gamma]^2 (x'')[t] == 0}, x''[t]] /. 
     x[t] -> x, v]},
 With[{cps = 
    Normal@SolveValues[vf == 0 && -2 <= x <= 2, {x, v}, Reals]},
  Manipulate[
   StreamPlot[vf, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {v, -2.5, 2.5},
    StreamPoints -> {{{{1, 1}, Green}, Automatic}},
    StreamColorFunction -> None,
    Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize@Large, Point[{1, 1}], Green, 
      Point[cps]},
    PlotLabel -> cps],
   {{k, 0.725}, 0.01, 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{\[Gamma], 1.}, 0.5, 3.}
   ]
  ]]


As k increases past k == 0.725 or so, the initial condition crosses the boundary between solutions cycling around the origin to those going off to infinity.
To prove they reach infinity in finite time takes more work than I have time for right now. I suspect they do, since on the right, we have x''[t] > constant*x[t]^5.

I tried to run your code, but it went wrong, it gives me the message:  Coordinate $CellContextSolveValues[False, {$CellContextx, $CellContextv}, Reals] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.. Why is that?

@Felps Perhaps x, v, or t has a value. Try Clear[x, v, t, k, \[Gamma]] and re-executing. The False in place of the equation to be solved in the error message shows something was defined already.

@MichaelE2 That's an interesting solution. To me it is still unclear why the direct numerical solution aborts. Any idea? Thanks!

As Bill Watts commented, the solution heads to infinity if you plot it. NDSolve[] can't integrate past a pole, so at some point, the step size must become smaller than the smallest step supported by the floating-point system.

@MichaelE2 Thank you for answer. I tried several initial conditions , NDSolve is able to integrate "over" the poles but stops with the stepsize message. Additionally, knowing the asymptotic behavior from your fine answer,  I tried to transform the ode, unfortunately without success

@UlrichNeumann '...NDSolve is able to integrate "over" the poles but stops with the stepsize message.' -- I've found none. Once x[t] gets above 10^6 or so, it soon stops with a zero-step-size error. What is an initial condition where NDSolve[] gets over the pole? I'm pretty sure the pole in all cases I've found is of the form $x(t) \sim c,(t-t_0)^{-1/2}$, where the pole at $t=t_0$ is close to the stopping point.

@MichaelE2 Thanks for your answer.  Perhaps I misunderstood what "pole" means. I thought it is an equilibrium point ( green dots in your plotl)

@UlrichNeumann No, I meant a vertical asymptote. The equilibrium points are on the boundary between the periodic solutions and those that blow up. (Well, except for the one at the origin, of course.)  [Sorry, for the constant updates.] The StreamPlot does not really show the asymptotes.

@MichaelE2 I got it, thanks again!

@UlrichNeumann You're welcome! :)
